# a panel or modal underneath a modal

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

Im new in web application and i came across the modal feature in bootstrap, i did researched and came across some examples that works perfectly fine but when i tried to copy what they did, an underlying image or panel or i dont know displays behind the modal... how to remove this? ive been trapped in this thing for like 3 days.. haha.. thanks...

Here is the image:-

[image]

and the code from w3schools... this should work but i dont know why..

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I checked your code of modal, This is coming fine.
 [check here](http://www.bootply.com/lTi3RTdoDp)

The problem is in your html kindly show us the entire html so that we can debug your code.

Comment: ive tried using this modal in my table... a modal should pop up when i click the "eye" icon... and it did but same problem, with the unnecessary background... im currently practicing MVC approach so hers my view code looks like...

Comment: Its better that you post the entire code here so that we can have a look,

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ryenocerous1996/kbmNu/297/ ... ive checked my code here... and it works just fine...

Comment: then why produce the image above? is it possible in the css file?

Comment: Are you talking about the panel ?

Comment: yes... i dont have any idea how that got there! hahaha .. ive also tried inspecting the elements by pressinfg F12, but i dont know how to fix it...

Comment: Do you have the website live ?

Comment: Okay. Have you missed any closing of div ?

Answer (score 0):

hi your code is working just fine. i find no problem with it.

[output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VClE.png)

hopefully problem with the browser?

Comment: i dunno, if it does, why do some examples in the net work perfectly... i guess there's some code in the MVC framework i have to bypass manually...